# как быстро получить три максимальных значения из базы данных Джанго?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model

попробовал Base.objects.order_by('value')[0:3] но это работало пока было мало записей. сейчас каждое упорядочивание занимает три секунды гдето а количество записей растет. Есть более быстрый способ?

Comment: сколько у вас записей в бд, что такой долгий поиск?

Comment: в базах данных для ускорения поиска/упорядочивания применяют индексы. см. [документацию](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/models/fields.html#db-index)

Comment: спасибо индексация помогла. почему то мне казалось что индексацию можно делать только для одного поля :) а записей в этой таблице которая вызывала проблемы не много полмиллиона гдето весом 400 Мб

Answer (score 0):

В модели попробуйте объявите сортировку по полю:

```
class Base(models.Model)
...
# Здесь объявлены ваши поля 
...

class Meta:
    ordering = ['value']
```

Comment: вот как раз думал чтоб предупредить чтоб не советовали упорядочить все заранее :) полей много. из всех нужно тащить максимальные и минимальные значение. по всем не упорядочишь :)

Answer (score 0):

не очень красиво, но можно сырым запросом, но для разных СУБД запрос немного будет отличаться. Для sqlite и mysql будет как-то так

```
Base.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_Base order by value limit 3')
```

Comment: нет времени ушло ровно столько же.

Comment: Значит затык уже на стороне СУБД. копайте там